# Making a loading screen in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have created a JFrame class with a button i want it so when you press the button it will take you to a splash screen without opening another JFrame. But how do i do this?. I want the new screen to have a image and a Loading GIF in the middle?

Answer (score 3):

What I like to do, is to use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and `JWindow`:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Splashscreen {
    JWindow window = new JWindow();

    public void start() {
        window.setSize(400, 300);
        // window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        new StartWorker().execute();
    }

    private class StartWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // Do background process
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(640, 480);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            // Dispose window when background process is finished
            window.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Splashscreen().start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, when you instantiate `Splashscreen` class and call `start` method `JWindow` will be displayed and `SwingWorker` will be executed. `JWindow` will be displayed until background process (time consuming task) is done. When process is done `JFrame` will be displayed and `JWindow` will be disposed.

But! In your case, I recommend to stick with `CardLayout` as MadProgrammer stated in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

> "I have created a JFrame class with a button i want it so when you
>   press the button it will take you to a splash screen without opening
>   another JFrame."

So we can assume this means you want the splash screen to be displayed using the current `JFrame` then.

You could use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between active "screens" or "panels"

If you are using a gif, the easiest solution would be to load the image via an `ImageIcon` and use a `JLabel` to render it (assuming it's an animated gif), otherwise you can take a look at [Reading/loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) to the the image (and display it via a `JLabel`)