# Is there a method to run another class

Tags: java, class, netbeans

When i click a Jbutton on my program. I want it to create a new screen like shown here.

[Making a loading screen in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665089/making-a-loading-screen-in-netbeans)

But the method is in another class, Can i make a method that will run another class file.

Comment: There is nothing we can help if you don't explain what exactly you want to do. Please follow [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to make a code example.

Comment: Show your current code, and show the code in "the other class".

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
Class cl = Class.forName(nameOfClass);
cl.getDeclaredMethod("main").invoke(null, new String[] {});
```

This will invoke the `main` method in the appropriate class with no args.

There are also a number of other ways, for example:

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("java", nameOfClass);
```

This will start another JVM for the other class. Now, the last way I know of:

```
NameOfClass.main(new String[] {});
```

This is a straight invocation of the main method with no args.

Comment: Although reflection API can works,  but I don't think that is suitable answer here.